# Python - Why wont wildcard bits work here?

Tags: python, wildcard

So I am trying to put wildcard bits in a path to a network folder. The path is here:

```
r"\\10.180.22.211\\Data\\DS~109803~Company~name of site\\Database"
```

The part between DATA and Database changes, but the rest of the path stays the exact same.  So when I actually put the entire path in, it works just fine, but if I try and change the middle part to wildcard bits it does not work.

```
r"\\10.180.22.211\\Data\\*\\Database"
```

OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: "\\10.180.22.211\\Data\\*\\Database"

I have tried *, '*', **, DS~*, *109803*, and several other combinations, and NONE of them with wildcard bits work at all. Can someone explain why they wont work and if there is a way to make wildcard bits work in this situation?

Edit:

Here is more of my code:

```
import os, shutil
import glob

ip = "10.180.22.211"
#ip = input("Input your IP: ")


directorya = r"\\10.180.22.211\\Jobdata\\*\\Database"
#directorya = r"\\10.180.22.211\\Jobdata\\DS~109803000~customer~job site\\Database"
directoryb = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test"

files = [file for file in os.listdir(directorya) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directorya, file))]
newest = max(glob.iglob(directorya + '\\*.*'), key=os.path.getctime)
print(newest)
shutil.copy(os.path.join(directorya, newest), directoryb)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two ways:

use list dir:

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    ......
```

or use glob:

```
import glob
path = "\10.180.22.211\Data\*\Database"
for filename in glob.glob(path):
    ....
```

get newest file:

```
    list_of_files = glob.glob('/path/to/folder/*')
    newest = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
    print newest
```

Comment: Im getting an error on your newest = max(list_of_files…… line now.  newest = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Comment: I added it to my last comment. But here it is again.       newest = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Comment: it seems that you get  empty list, maybe somthing related to the whitespaces in your path, try to print the  list_of_files to check what you got

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194220/discussion-between-lzypenguin-and-tonyjafar).